# How to Simplify Sin/tan problem.

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

I am trying to simplify $\displaystyle\frac{\sin^2}{\tan^2}$ but I don't know how to go about it. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You’re aware that $\tan=\sin/\cos$?

Comment: @Lubin yes I am aware.

Comment: Then it’s just a matter of doing that substitution and simplifying the complicated fraction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you know that
$$\tan^2\theta=\frac{\sin^2\theta}{\cos^2\theta}$$
You can rewrite this in terms of $\sin^2\theta$.
$$\sin^2\theta=\tan^2\theta\cdot\cos^2\theta$$
The fraction $\dfrac{\sin^2\theta}{\tan^2\theta}$ can be rewritten as:
$$\frac{\color{red}{\tan^2\theta}\cdot\cos^2\theta}{\color{red}{\tan^2\theta}}$$
Cancelling the $\tan^2\theta$ in the numerator and the denominator gives us $\cos^2\theta$
$$\displaystyle \color{green}{\therefore \frac{\sin^2\theta}{\tan^2\theta}=\cos^2\theta}$$

Answer (score 4):

Hint:
$$
\frac{\sin^2}{\tan^2}=\frac{\sin^2}{\frac{\sin^2}{\cos^2}}
$$
Can you simplify this fraction?